# PHP Admin Account

Tags: php, jquery, html, authentication, user-accounts

On my website, I want a few options to be enabled when someone logs in with an admin account. My question is about how to secure that admin account as much as possible. They way login is setup on my website is after authenticating login, i do this `$_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';` and then i say something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    if(<?php echo ($_SESSION['status'] == 'authorized'); ?>) {
        $('#account_window').show();
    }
});
</script>

<div id="account_window">
    //account stuff
</div>
```

With the addition of the master account I was thinking about adding this `$_SESSION['master'] = 'authorized';` and then in the front page, I would add this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    if(<?php echo ($_SESSION['status'] == 'authorized'); ?>) {
        $('#account_window').show();
    }
});
</script>

<div id="account_window">
    //account stuff
    <?php if($_SESSION['master'] == 'authorized') { ?>
        <div id="master_account">
            //admin stuff like send users emails
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

But I feel like that is too easy, is that a safe way to authenticate the master account? If not, what is the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: What would stop me using inspect element in the browser and displaying this hidden div? you should **authorize** against the database and not in session.

Comment: It is safe as far as safe session functional, so - yes. KISS

Comment: hiding content when not authorised is big security failure if they look at the html coding they will see everything..plus sessions should be validated against the user, for example if you have db records belong to the user A and user B if they wanted can highjack into user A content and delete them.. if you just check the user session status only. remember it only says you login only but it doenst say you are authorised to do edit other peoples stuff..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be tempting to just "hide" the admin interface from non-admins, but that's fundamentally bypassable if someone just injects the right HTML into the page (e.g. with a GreaseMonkey script), or generates the requests manually.

You have to validate every action in PHP in order to get any actual security. Therefore, you need to check that the user is authorized when they submit any forms or commit an action, in PHP.

Comment: okay so are you saying I should have a `checklogin` or `checkadmin` function that i should call to show/hide the div?

Comment: No. What I'm saying is that you need to validate the request they make through that interface. Say they make a request to send an email. The PHP script that handles that request must check that the user is authorized to send emails before actually doing it.

Comment: you should not even output the html for user which are not allowed to use this functionality because anyone can easily inspect the html in the browser and show the hidden stuff. as the actions a user peforms are anyhow sent to the server it much easer and safer to check the permissions there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate every action in PHP in order to get any actual security. Therefore, you need to check that the user is authorized when they submit any forms or commit an action, in PHP.