# PHP Account Security

Tags: php, html, security, authentication, code-injection

Currently I have a site that hides the account window where you can change password, upload files, etc. The code is simple as:

```
<?php if($is_logged_in) { ?>
      <div id="account_window">
          //stuff
      </div>
<?php } ?>
```

But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095387/php-admin-account) that's a big security flaw. So what is the alternative? How can I make the account window viewable only if the user has logged in and do it in a more secure manner that is not susceptible `if someone just injects the right HTML into the page`?

Comment: You might want to read through this great [list of security best practices](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAppSec/Secure_Coding_Guidelines) by Mozilla. It looks scary, but lists the most common pitfalls when implementing authorization in web apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link deals with jQuery - the HTML will be on the page no matter what and jQuery simply shows/hides it. I could run some JS to show the div even though I'm not logged in.

You're doing it with PHP - the page gets rendered on the server and only the visible HTML gets sent back to the browser. If the user is not logged in, the account_window div will never make it to the browser. I can't do anything because the secured HTML isn't on the page at all.

Comment: ah i see, so what you're saying is if I use the php if statement then the people won't even be able to see that html therefore they can't manipulate it. Also are sessions at all manipulate-able? I mean if I use `$_SESSION['authorized']=true;` is that in any way changeable so the user can be authorized when they shouldnt be?

Comment: Sessions get stored on the server. On the client is a cookie that contains the ID of the session. Users can change the cookie, but you'd have to know what to change it to to make it point to a valid session of a logged in user to gain access. So sessions are safe.

Answer (score 3):

That's the jQuery part I guess, it only hides the data, but it is rendered on the page, if you see the source you can see the hidden data, it acts like CSS `display: none;` property here content is actually on the page but just hidden on screen

In PHP you can also use `$_SESSION` data for hiding like

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true

<?php if($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) { ?>
      <div id="account_window">
          //stuff
      </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that the `$is_logged_in` variable is only set if the user is logged in. So:

If the 'account stuff' are input boxes and textareas or anything that the user inputs info to be transmitted to the server-side scripts through, the only security flaw there is is if you do not check again during data submission whether the user is logged in. If you do not check that, the user can inject HTML and make a submission which will be stored in the database. That is the only Security Flaw.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be secure (as long as `$is_logged_in` does not come from a query parameter!). In the other post that you referenced, the OP was including the account-related html whether or not the user was logged in, and displaying it with JavaScript if the user was logged in - this is quite a bit different, and if your page is being rendered on the server without the account information, it will be safe. The only thing that you need to worry about is making sure that users cannot interfere with how `$is_logged_in` is set.